# Reflexão sobre o número de votantes na eleição

Tags: debate, eleição

Não há dúvida que os eleitos estão de parabéns.

Mas será que podemos dizer que a comunidade está de parabéns?

Vejamos os números:

- 1,067 votantes qualificados.
- 366 visitaram o site durante a eleição.
- 345 visitaram a página de eleição.
- 107 votaram.

Seria talvez demagógico, apesar de estatisticamente correcto, dizer que a *"afluência às urnas"* foi apenas de 10%.

Digo *talvez demagógico* porque, na verdade, só 366 visitaram o site nessa altura, não tendo os outros, presumo eu, conhecimento de que decorria a eleição.

É de realçar no entanto, como algo positivo, o facto que desses 366, 345 visitaram a página da eleição.

Positivo porque 94% dos visitantes qualificados mostraram interesse pela eleição ao visitarem a página a ela dedicada.

Então, e esta é a questão que deixo para comentarem, estará a comunidade de parabéns quando apenas <s>10%</s> 31% de eleitores votaram?

Comment: É uma excelente pergunta. Dá que pensar realmente. Os meus eleitores de certeza que são os 59% que faltam :P

Comment: @JorgeB. 69% queres tu dizer. Seria muito difícil mas mantive alguma esperança que fosse eleito um moderador deste lado do atlântico.

Comment: Sim isso :P @ramaral o Sergio esteve quase...

Comment: @JorgeB. Onde posso encontrar os resultados por candidato?

Comment: http://www.opavote.org/results/5243642608353280/0

Comment: O buraco é até mais embaixo, mas não vou entrar nessa polêmica, não estou com tempo pra isso :) Está faltando representatividade. E aproveito para dizer que acho que deveria ter um moderador europeu, talvez tenha ocorrido uma divisão de votos.

Comment: @bigown Viva! É bom vê-lo de novo. Também seria bom ver algum comentário por parte dos moderadores, esperava mais participação. Não quer explicar o que quis dizer com *"O buraco é até mais embaixo"*?

Comment: Eu acreditava ser importante ter representantes de outros países com grande percentual participante aqui no SOpt (no caso Portugal), pois teria talvez outra visão da comunidade. Apesar de meus votos terem sido pensando nisso (2 Brasileiros e 1 Português), isso não ocorreu =(. Mas ainda teremos um representante no outro lado do oceano, mas não do Atlântico, e sim do Pacifico (segundo o @utluiz, ele está indo morar com os cangurus boxeadores. Hehe)

Comment: @ramaral dá para fazer um *revival* mais tarde :) Dessa vez deve se aproximar dos 25% de votanates.

Comment: @bigown Como sabe? Ainda não há resultados.

Comment: @ramaral ainda é chute, na verdade acho que ficará pouco acima de 20% tem uns 1800/1900 qualificados, já votaram mais de 350. Eu adoro números :)

Comment: @bigown Uma coisa boa que o números(estatísticas) têm é que podem ser vistos de farias formas(normalmente da forma que nos dá mais jeito). Veja assim: a participação duplicou :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse post, mais algumas conversas no chat da eleição, me deixaram curioso sobre o nível de participação em eleições por toda a rede. Nós tivemos em torno de 117 eleições em 52 sites até agora, que é um corpo significativo o suficiente pra tentar aprender como as comunidades se comportam.

Infelizmente, descobri que nós não temos esses dados de maneira acessível. Ao final de cada eleição, suas estatísticas são calculadas e é gerado um texto, adicionado no final do [texto sobre a eleição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/1):

> 1,067 votantes estavam qualificados, 366 visitaram o site durante a eleição, 345 visitaram a página de eleição e 107 votaram

Esse texto é armazenado, mas seus dados não. Além disso o texto variou ao longo dos anos, o que dificulta fazer a varredura e retirar os valores. *Dificulta*, mas não torna *impossível*!

[image: XKCD!]
<sup><sup>Fonte:[XKCD](https://xkcd.com/208/) | Tradução: [Tirinhas.com](http://www.tirinhas.com/xkcd.php?tira=208)</sup></sup>

## Google Sheets ao Resgate

Por uma completa falta de senso de autopreservação, eu peguei todas as mensagens até hoje, varri esses dados e [**coloquei numa planilha pública**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wj8pzSiZU4rja5gSx9NEl1-MSzNFYa1sqMGIXt0kNyE/edit?usp=sharing). Não tá bonito, não é simpático, não tem boa usabilidade, mas é o que temos.

As colunas estão agrupadas por tipo de informação, e cruzam umas com as outras. Seus valores são derivados do texto ao final de cada eleição:

- **Total Eleitores**
  Quantos usuários estavam aptos a votar nessa eleição
- **Acessos ao Site**
  Quantos usuários acessaram o site durante a eleição
- **% Eleitores**
  Que proporção de potenciais eleitores acessou o site durante a eleição
- **Acessos à Eleição**
  Quantos usuários acessaram a página da eleição durante a eleição
- **% Eleitores**
  Que proporção de potenciais eleitores acessou a página da eleição durante a eleição
- **% Acessos ao Site**
  Que proporção do número de pessoas que acessou o site também visitou a página da eleição
- **Votantes**
  Quantas pessoas votaram
- **% Eleitores**
  Que proporção do total de eleitores possíveis efetivamente votou
- **% Acessos à Eleição**
  Que proporção do número de pessoas que acessou a página da eleição também votou

Algumas células estão em vermelho porque aquele valor não estava presente no texto original, como na [primeira eleição do Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1) que não tem o número de acessos ao site durante a eleição:

> 43,778 voters were eligible, 14,130 visited the election, and 4,970 voted
>
> ---
>
> 43,778 votantes estavam qualificados, 14,130 visitaram a página da eleição, e 4,970 votaram

A planilha tem, no cabeçalho, a [média](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9dia) e a [mediana](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediana_(estat%C3%ADstica)) de cada coluna.

## Como está nossa Democracia SOptana?

Avaliando o SOpt contra a média (e mediana), nós estamos muito bem em alguns quesitos e pra trás em outros.

O número de eleitores que acessou o site durante a eleição está dentro do normal, principalmente se considerarmos o tamanho da nossa comunidade. Quanto maior a comunidade, maior tende a ser o número de usuários não-assíduos com reputação suficiente para votar. Nosso número está abaixo de alguns sites de tamanho similar ao nosso, mas acima de outros. Ele decididamente pode melhorar (vide o SOen, com >60%) mas não é preocupante.

Depois disso, temos o número de "acessantes" que visitou a página da eleição. E nisso nós estamos de parabéns. Praticamente todo eleitor que visitou o site, também visitou a eleição. O que mostra o interesse alto da comunidade pelo processo de escolha dos moderadores.

O problema é que esse número de interessados não se converteu em **votos**. Só ~30% das pessoas que visitaram a página da eleição acabaram votando (seja nas primárias ou na eleição). Isso é algo que nos deixou bem abaixo da média, ainda que similares ao que acontece no SOen.

A comparação com o SOen é relevante porque, apesar de termos uma fração do tamanho, o assunto de um site tem influência nas características da sua comunidade. Então, apesar de sermos menores, nossa comunidade não se comporta muito diferente (em termos de transiência de usuários, atividade média, etc). E isso se reflete no interesse pela eleição.

## Conclusão

Algo pode ter acontecido para causar uma queda tão brusca entre visitar a eleição e efetivamente votar. Os números definitivamente não são preocupantes. Eles são similares aos de comunidades com características parecidas com as nossas. Não significam que não devemos trabalhar para melhorá-los, seja fazendo divulgação melhor da eleição, ou incentivando o voto de maneira mais contundente, ou até pensando em como manter mais pessoas no site.

Nossa eleição foi muito bem sucedida, e os eleitos estão fazendo um excelente trabalho. Só temos como melhorar.

Comment: Obrigado pela pesquisa e tratamento dos dados. Apesar de concordar consigo em que *" o assunto de um site tem influência nas características da sua comunidade."*, apenas saber que de certa forma seguimos o comportamento do SOen não me conforta. O importante é que sabemos onde as coisas correram mal, isso permitirá direccionar os nossos esforços de melhoria para aí.

Comment: @ramaral Concordo plenamente. De maneira alguma quis passar uma impressão de acomodação. Mas o SOen (e os outros sites de tamanho similar ao SOpt) são parâmetros que nos deixam entender melhor onde e quanto estamos indo mal, e quanto podemos esperar melhorar no futuro. Nós só sabemos que o incentivo ao voto seria mais benéfico que uma divulgação mais ampla das eleições porque sabemos que o a  proporção de votantes é a estatística que mais destoa da "norma".

Answer (score 10):

Não tenho dados concretos ou estudos detalhados para sustentar o que vou dizer a seguir, mas esta é a impressão/intuição que tenho.

Primeiro, vamos dividir os usuários que estavam aptos a votar em três grupos:

1. **Usuários inativos:** O requisito mínimo para votar são 150 pontos de reputação. Há muitos usuários que estão abaixo dos 500 ou 600 pontos que são usuários inativos, são aqueles que visitavam o site no passado, mas deixaram de frequentar por qualquer motivo. Há até mesmo alguns poucos usuários com mais de 1000 pontos que não aparecem por aqui há meses.
2. **Usuários com atividade passageira:** Também há usuários que embora ativos no momento, aptos a votar e ciente do processo eleitoral, não têm nenhum interesse em votar. Em geral são aqueles que estão aqui há pouco tempo, fazem algumas perguntas até que boas (e ganhando reputação) visando resolver os seus problemas e depois de alguns dias, vão embora.
3. **Usuários ativos:** São os usuários de reputação alta que sempre aparecem por aqui, além de um bom número dos usuários de reputação mais baixa que estão em ascenção e pretendem se dedicar ao site no futuro.

O grupo 1 é o maior grupo de usuários aptos a votar, e faz sentido crer que neste grupo quase ninguém votou.

O grupo 2 também é numeroso, mas não tanto quanto o grupo 1. Alguns poucos destes usuários até devem ter votado, mas a grande maioria destes nem tinha porque querer fazer isso, uma vez que não pretendem participar da comunidade em um longo prazo, desconhecem os então candidatos a moderador e provavelmente nem sequer entenderam como a eleição funcionara e nem tinham motivo para querer saber isso.

No grupo 3 quase todos votaram. Os que deixaram de votar são muito poucos e provavelmente não votaram por algum motivo tal como terem ficado indecisos e no final não terem votado nada, ou simplesmente terem perdido o prazo da votação, ou por algum motivo terem decidido que seria melhor se abster.

Qual que é o tamanho do grupo 3? Não sei ao certo (embora não seja difícil de descobrir), mas acredito que dentro deste grupo tivemos um grande comparecimento, o que significa que a comunidade está de parabéns. Também me parece que tivemos um bom número de votos do grupo 2, o que reforça essa ideia. E em geral, não há motivo para se importar muito com o grupo 1.

Answer (score 6):

(Não tinha espaço para um comentário então eu vou colocar como resposta.)

A minha resposta é do ponto de vista de um eleitor +- ativo.

Eu quase perdi a votação. Acompanhei durante semanas e quase perdi o prazo. Acho que quando votei faltavam algumas horas.

Acredito que um dos problemas foi a má divulgação e certa confusão na execução dos processos. Tivemos um link em destaque durante 1 ou 2 meses onde vc clicava e levava para uma página vazia. Vários membros questionaram e não houve resposta alguma, pelo menos eu não fiquei a par de resolução alguma. Então de repente surge os pré-candidatos. Ok, estavam lá todos lindos fazendo o seu merchandise hehe.

Veio então o período de indicação de candidatos. Mas eu fiquei bem confuso, eu não vi nenhum local onde poderia indicar um candidato. Como que tinha que fazer? 
Realmente confuso. Desisti e fiquei esperando o dia de votação.

Nesse meio tempo fiquei muito ocupado com compromissos pessoais e um dia acessei aqui e fiquei curioso de ver como estava as votações e tomei um susto! Restavam algumas horas para terminar! eu estava crente de que ainda tinha 1 semana para votar.

Votei nos 3 guapos que eu já tinha escolhido semanas atrás e fiquei tranquilo.

Enfim, acho que os problemas foram a má divulgação e problemas técnicos.

Claro que tem também o percentual daqueles que perdem o prazo ou que são meramente curiosos e não dão muita importância, mas acho que os problemas técnicos pesaram bastante por desmotivar os que tinham algum interesse.

Comment: Julgo que 4 dias é pouco para a *fase 2* e *fase 3* tendo esta última apanhado um fim de semana.

Comment: É o fim de semana não ajudou muito não. Deveria ter sido em dias úteis.

Comment: então outro problema foi a logística em si.. os fatos pesam mais para lado administrativo do que para os membros do site. A administração deve refletir também.

Comment: O período e a divulgação da nossa eleição foram iguais aos dos outros sites. Definitivamente não é um processo perfeito, mas é tudo que podemos fazer.

Comment: O link para a página vazia ficou no ar por menos de uma semana. Mas é interessante essa sua sensação de que ficou por 1 ou 2 meses, mostra o quanto a experiência de usuário é importante, e o quanto esse tipo de falha pode afetar as pessoas. Eu concordo que o formato da eleição é bastante diferente (pelo menos para nós brasileiros), o que também influencia.

Comment: aquele link vazio , para mim, durou bem mais que 1 semana.. posso afirmar que pelo menos 1 mês ficou daquele daquele jeito.. Inclusive postei aqui no meta pois estava me incomodando e já tinha outros questionando. O problema maior no link vazio é a sensação de desleixo e ainda mais por não ver resposta por parte da administração.  Se teve resposta, eu também não vi... Ficou essa sensação de algo "feito nas coxas"..  Obviamente não pode-se exigir perfeição, mas um mínimo de senso lógico deve-se ter. Apesar de tudo, bola pra frente. Temos muito que aprender e evoluir

Comment: @DanielOmine O link para a eleição vazia foi pro ar dia 01/06, por acidente (como explicado [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3844/12)). No dia 08/06, 1 semana depois, nossas eleições começaram. Todo mundo recebeu um *novo* aviso na caixa de entrada, e o link no "boletim da comunidade" estava apontando pro lugar certo, com a URL da nossa eleição. Se uma dessas 2 coisas não ocorreu com você, deve ter havido algum problema técnico...