# Resultado da Eleição para Moderador 2016

Tags: debate, eleição

A [segunda eleição do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/2) chegou ao fim. Depois da contagem de votos, nós temos 2 novos moderadores:

[image: bigown] [image: rray]

Eles se juntam ao [bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto), [utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/227/utluiz), [Math](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3117/math) e [Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio) na equipe de moderadores do site!

**Parabéns aos 2!**

Essa é nossa nova [equipe de moderação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). É hora de dar boas vindas, e parabéns, a quem chega. Obrigado também a todos os outros candidatos, que se dispuseram a ajudar ainda mais o SOpt.

Para ver mais detalhes, basta fazer download do [arquivo de auditoria](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/2), ou [ver o resumo online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6318281803694080/0).

Comment: Parabéns aos dois :D

Comment: Parabéns, bigown e rray ! Que vcs sejam como moderadores, tão atenciososo quanto users...;)

Comment: Parabéns ao novos mods e bem vindos ao time \o/

Comment: Parabéns aos dois :)

Comment: Parabéns, bem-vindos ao time!

Comment: Parabéns para os dois ! =D

Comment: Much votes. Such democracy. Wow

Comment: Parabéns, agora só falta Gabe organizar o churrasco e me convidar

Comment: Parabéns aos dois, e a todos que concorreram a eleição, afinal, todos nós somos moderadores, de certa forma, e é nosso dever cobrar aos moderadores, assim como fiscalizar o seu trabalho. \ô/

Comment: Parabéns rray e bigown!!!

Comment: Parabéns aos dois, bigown e rray. Venceram essa eleição de forma fácil e rápida - veni, vidi, vici.

Comment: Parabéns aos dois, grandes colaboradores da comunidade!

Comment: Gabe, pode verificar os números dos resultados. Penso não ser possível o número dos que visitaram a página da eleição ser superior ao número dos que visitaram o site. Procurei pela página onde eles foram publicados, para colocar um link na minha resposta, mas não a encontro.

Comment: @ramaral Posso, mas se bem me lembro da última vez que olhei isso, os números gerados pra essa estatística - exceto o de votantes - não são dos mais confiáveis, ou fáceis de verificar. Mas vou dar uma investigada hoje

Comment: Julgo que devem estar errados(talvez trocados) porque não é possível visitar a  página da eleição sem visitar o site.

Comment: @ramaral aí vai depender de como o sistema conta "visitar o site"

Comment: Sim, acredito que seja isso, mas julgo que uma visita à página da eleição deveria contar como uma visita ao site(claro que isso só é importante para a estatística de participação).

Comment: @ramaral podem ser vistos aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/election Durante as fases de candidatura e primárias esses números eram visíveis para os mods, o número dos visitantes do site ficaram zerados o tempo inteiro, só começaram a contabilizar durante a fase da eleição. Já o número de visitantes da página da eleição sempre esteve a contabilizar. Talvez foi isso que aconteceu, os 689 visitantes do site se referem apenas a última etapa da eleição.

Comment: Tanto "Parabéns" que tá parecendo grupo do Whatsapp. Mas "parabéns" também

Comment: @Math obrigado. Ao contrário do que eu disse anteriormente, uma vez esclarecido, julgo que o modo como está feita a contagem é correcta. A página existe durante as 3 fases enquanto que a eleição se refere apenas à última.

Comment: @ramaral poisé, e como se trata de uma tradução tinha que ver o texto original para talvez deixar mais claro o entendimento, pois o o termo "eleição" pode se referir a todo o processo ou apenas à última etapa.

Comment: Parabéns aos dois e ao @ramaral pela resposta abaixo.

Comment: Parabéns AEEE @rray e @bigown!!! E assim sobe o nível da nossa comunidade... \o/ \o/ \o/

Comment: Parabéns para os dois!! :)

Comment: Excelente! Parabéns a ambos!

Comment: Parabéns @@rray  @bigown e obrigado por compartilhar o conhecimento.

Comment: Parabéns a dupla 0//

Comment: Parabens @Bigown, ja me ajudou muito por ai. valeu

Answer (score 44):

Há pouco mais de um ano, nas eleições de 2015, uma [publicação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4021/2541) minha, aqui no meta, começava assim:

> Não há dúvida que os eleitos estão de parabéns.
>
> Mas será que podemos dizer que a comunidade está de parabéns?

Com os [resultados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election) de hoje:

- 1,885 votantes qualificados.
- 689 visitaram o site durante a última fase da eleição.
- 825 visitaram a página da eleição.
- 360 votaram.

Ao votaram 19% dos qualificados e 44% dos que visitaram a página da eleição, houve um aumento de participação de 90% e 42% respectivamente.

**Tendo em conta o aumento significativo da participação, não só estão de parabéns os eleitos como está também a comunidade.**

Comment: Depois de vasculhar o codigo fonte, conseguir entender como o número de "visitantes do site" é maior que o de "visitantes da eleição". Nessa estatísitca, "visita ao site" segue os mesmos requisitos de "visita ao site" quando se quer ganhar as medalhas [Entusiasta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/54) ou [Fanático](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/55). Não podemos divulgar quais são os requisitos, mas é necessário mais do que só visitar a homepage. Assim, essas 136 pessoas visitaram a eleição, mas não satisfizeram os requisitos para contar como "visita ao site".

Comment: @Gabe Obrigado. Diga-me por favor se o texto, que eu coloquei à frente de cada número, reflecte o que cada um deles representa.

Answer (score 19):

**@bigown** e **@rray**, como moderador, o melhor que posso dizer é um grande...

> ## Bem-Vindo!

Vocês sempre fizeram muita diferença no site e merecem cada voto que tiveram.

A partir de agora, tendo o aval da comunidade, poderão de fazer ainda mais.

Parabéns!

## ☆彡(ノ^^)ノ☆彡ヘ(^^ヘ)☆彡(ノ^^)ノ☆彡